# Oracle Cursor and JDBC ODBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc, odbc, sys-refcursor

I have some procedures to execute in the database that has an OUT REFCURSOR parameter.

When I am connecting with the JDBC thin client, everything works fine. However, if I were to change the connection string to refer to the ODBC data source pointing to the same database, those procedures will fail. The procedures that do not use an OUT REFCURSOR will still work fine though.

Is this situation the result of an error on my part or expected?

Comment: Why bother with the JDBC-ODBC bridge? It is buggy and slow. Oracle has a decent JDBC driver, so I don't see the need to use the JDBC-ODBC bridge...

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for calling procedures returning REFCURSOR is different for the two drivers. So unless you change the call syntax it is to be expected.